# How to make a "room" on WebSocket

Tags: node.js

I am playing with WebRTC "library", which allows user to transfer audio, video, etc. by peer-2-peer connection. 
To do this I need to initiate a connection by WebSocket in my internet explorer.

I have choosen heroku.com as my node.js hosting.

This is my server file, I need to add user to the 'room', but it crashes like you can see below:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
var http = require("http");
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index')
});

app.get('/cool', function(request, response) {
  response.send(cool());
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"))

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)

console.log("http server listening on %d", port)

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server})
console.log("websocket server created")

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
  console.log("websocket connection open")

  ///////////////
  // I NEED HELP HERE
  ws.on('message', function(room) {
        console.log("I am trying to create room: " + room);

        ws.join(room); // this line is crashing
                        // with error "There is NO function join"


    });

  ws.on("close", function() {
    console.log("websocket connection close")
  })
})
```

This is my client side, where I sent name of the room, which I want to create:

```
var host = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
var ws = new WebSocket(host);
waitForSocketConnection(ws);
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log('got ' + event);
    console.log('got2 ' + event.data);
};

function waitForSocketConnection(socket){
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                    socket.send("Lukasz30M");
                    return;
                } else {
                    waitForSocketConnection(socket);
                }
            }, 5);
    };
```

This is WebRTC provided example, which I am trying to follow:

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new(static.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(2013);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

  // convenience function to log server messages on the client
    function log(){
        var array = [">>> Message from server: "];
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        array.push(arguments[i]);
      }
        socket.emit('log', array);
    }

    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        log('Got message:', message);
    // for a real app, would be room only (not broadcast)
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('create or join', function (room) {
        var numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length;

        log('Room ' + room + ' has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
        log('Request to create or join room ' + room);

        if (numClients === 0){
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('created', room);
        } else if (numClients === 1) {
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('joined', room);
        } else { // max two clients
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
        socket.emit('emit(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
        socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);

    });

});
```

Thank you for you directions. I've tottaly stopped ;)

Answer (score -2):

wrtc non permette collegamenti a pagine non sicure. devi avere un collegamento https.

---

WRTC does not allow links to non-secure pages. you must have a https connection

Comment: @PetterFriberg It depends. If it's something like this where Google appears to make a reasonable translation then make the edit. If it's a lot of text and/or the translation makes little or no sense then comment/downvote/flag.

Comment: @BhargavRao technically yes. But as I said, if the automatic translation works (which is what I use to see if the answers actually spam or rude) then I see no harm in making the edit. If you have to do any more work than that then flag. Use your judgement. If you do flag but I decide to do the translation I will mark your flag as helpful.